# I want to implement WorkManager for Periodic work every one minute but WorkManager not work properly so how to implement?

Tags: java, android, android-workmanager, periodic-task

Here is my worker class:

```
public class DataContinueWork extends Worker {

    public DataContinueWork(Context context,
                            WorkerParameters workerParams) {
        super(context, workerParams);
    }

    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
        addInDatabase();
        return Result.Success.success();
    }

    private void addInDatabase() {
        DatabaseHelper database = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(), DatabaseHelper.class, "database").build();
        DatabaseModel databaseModel = new DatabaseModel();
        Date date = new Date();
        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EE d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss aaa");

        Log.e("avrge", "getArge - --->>>> " + tempTotal1 / tempCounter1);
        databaseModel.setOtTemp(String.valueOf(tempTotal1 / tempCounter1));
        tempTotal1 = 0;
        tempCounter1 = 0;
        Log.e("avrge", "val tempTotal cont - --->>>> " + tempTotal1 + " " + tempCounter1);
       
        databaseModel.setTime(simpleDateFormat.format(date));
        database.getDao().insert(databaseModel);
    }
}
```

And here initialize my work in background:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    PeriodicWorkRequest periodicWork = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(DataContinueWork.class,
            1, TimeUnit.MINUTES,1 ,TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();

    WorkManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(String.valueOf(periodicWork),
            ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP, periodicWork);


    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

But the worker not working every minute so now what do I do?

I want to add data to the database every minute but the worker not working properly.

Data add but not added every minute [see database log here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqTlt.png)

Comment: `Periodic work has a minimum interval of 15 minutes.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/PeriodicWorkRequest)

"Periodic work has a minimum interval of 15 minutes."

So you cannot use a PeriodicWorkRequest.

In some experimentation I did with Work Manager, to get a periodic work request around every minute you can create a `OneTimeWorkRequest` and then `setInitialDelay` of 1 minute and then Observe the WorkRequest for the three completed states and then trigger the next `OneTimeWorkRequest` when the first had finished.

If you try and re-use the same work request for each time you might have problems with using the same ID, but you can work around that with a kludge of [pruning](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager#pruneWork()) the work manager to remove old requests before scheduling the next.

The are also other ways to trigger multiple OneTimeWorkRequest's with a minutes delay.

Comment: Better to use a `Foreground Service` instead of continuously rescheduling & firing of WorkRequests.

Comment: @Darshan using `Foreground Services` might not be a better answer it all depends on the exact requiremnets but Androids background processing guide https://developer.android.com/guide/background says "Android 12 restricts launching foreground services from the background. For most cases, you should use setForeground() from WorkManager rather than handle foreground services yourself."